# Java regex replacing all the characters except few combination of characters

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

Input String : `NNULL(EUR,VALUE)+SOMESTR`

Expected output:`NNULL(X,X)+X`

Expression tried:

```
String str = "NNULL(EUR,VALUE)+SOMESTR";
str=str.replaceAll("[^(NNULL)\\+,]+","X");
```

Output getting:

```
NNULL(XUX,XLUX)+X
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear for me. Could you explain logic you are trying to implement? What ware you trying to achieve via `[^(NNULL)\\+,]`? What is so regular about input string (what are assumptions we can make)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you imagine the output you want would be produced?

The `[...]` syntax is a character class. It matches individual characters. Negating the class matches any character not in the class. So `[^(NNULL)\\+,]` matches every character that isn't one of `(`, `N`, `U`, etc.

It seems like what you want to do is tokenize the string according to a set of rules that you haven't clearly defined, and then replace certain tokens.

First, define a simple regex that will match a single 'token'. From your question, I'm guessing you want to consider words and symbols, so the tokens would be `NNULL`, `(`, `EUR`, `,`, `VALUE`, `)`, `+`, `X`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+|\\W"); // a word, or a single non-word character
```

Now, find a way to specify which tokens to keep and which to replace. I used a Set containing the 'good' tokens, but any string predicate will work.

```
Set<String> retain = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("NNULL", "(", ")", ",", "+"));
```

All we have to do now is loop through the tokens (as identified by the regex) and see if they're in the 'good' set or not.

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
while(m.find()) {
    String token = m.group();
    result.append(retain.contains(token) ? token : "X");
}
```

*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*

Comment: ,Thanks for suggestion.I am aware that programmatically it can be done using regex. I was not sure if there is a direct way of doing it by regular exp tokenization in one shot.Hence the question posted.Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a positive look behind with `(`, `,` or `+`

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pB4tP4/2)

```
String str = "NNULL(EUR,VALUE)+SOMESTR";
str=str.replaceAll("(?<=[(,+])\\w+","X");
System.out.println(str); // NNULL(X,X)+X
```

Comment: It could be just `(?<=[(,+])\\w+`, you don't need to escape chars in `[...]`.

Comment: @nicael Thanks I did not know that :)

Comment: @YassinHajaj. This does solve the problem but Sam's solution is more generic. For e.g. "NNULL(EUR,VALUE)+NNULL(SOMESTR,1)";

Comment: @Puneet No problem, hope it helped a little a least :)

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested pattern `[^NNULL]` does not mean anything but `NNULL`, it means anything not in the character class `NNULL` with `N` being duplicate here.

Use this pattern instead

```
\b(?!NNULL)[^(),+]+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pB4tP4/3)

```
\b              # <word boundary>
(?!             # Negative Look-Ahead
  NNULL         # "NNULL"
)               # End of Negative Look-Ahead
[^(),+]         # Character not in [(),+] Character Class
+               # (one or more)(greedy)
```